# How to open url to the same tab if its already open in browser

Tags: html, jsp, browser, tabs, href

I am facing some challenge-
Lets consider I have a menu and under that I have 3 links-

```
About
Contact Us
FAQs
```

By default home page is About menu item.
Now when I am clicking on "**Contact Us**" , I want to open a new tab on same browser window. And without closing this if again I am clinking on "**Contact Us**" from the first tab, `this time I do not want to open new tab because I have already an open tab for Contact us`, I just wanted to navigate to the same one which is earlier opened.
How to handle this scenario in jsp.

Is there any way to do this. please help me.

Answer (score 8):

you can always put a name in the target so it will always go to the same window/tab

```
<a href="somerandomurl.com" target="mywindow">Contact Us<\a>
```

Its not possible to control this on Internet explorer.
You can however change how IE behaves:
-Internet Options
-Tabs
-Always open pop-ups in a new tab
-Open links from other programs in: A new tab in the current window

`target="_blank"` will always make sure it opens in a new window
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

It will however refresh the page with the same url

You can have the link return a javascript window object and be able to return to the window anytime you want without refreshing the page

```js
var newtab = null;

function openwindow(){
  if (newtab==null) {
    newtab = window.open("www.example.com");
  } else {
    newtab.focus();
  }

}
```

```html
<a onclick="openwindow()">click me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help Enfantcool. I tried the same and its working fine. But in IE it is opening new window instead of new tab. any luck on that?

Comment: Its not possible to control this on Internet explorer.
You can however change how IE behaves:
-Internet Options
-Tabs
-Always open pop-ups in a new tab
-Open links from other programs in: A new tab in the current window

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work if someone refresh the parent page also, it will close the child tab if that tab is already open on refresh of parent page.
Javascript:

```
<script>
        var newtab = null;
        window.open('', 'business-list', '').close();
        function openwindow() {
            if (!newtab || newtab.closed) {
                newtab = window.open("/admin/business-list.aspx","business-list");
            } else {
                newtab.focus();
            }

        }
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="openwindow()" style="cursor:pointer">Business List</a>
```